# Are their pairs of Nuclear Isobars that differ in energy by less then the Lighter Nuclides Characteristic X-ray?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, x-rays, isotopes, electron-capture

Isobars are atoms (nuclides) of different chemical elements that have the same number of nucleons.
According to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mattauch_isobar_rule if you have two adjacent elements on the periodic table have isotopes of the same mass number, one of these isotopes must be radioactive.
The decay can happen by positron emission, Electron capture of Beta decay.

When electron capture occurs, there will be a hole in the first electron shell that will quickly be filled by an electron from a higher shell, giving of what's called a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_X-ray

Something I've realised though is that if the Isobar with more protons is the heavier Nuclide, but the mass difference is less then the Characteristic X-ray of the lighter Nuclide, then it would be impossible to decat via capture of an electron from the innermost shell. Are there any Nuclides where this is the case?